# a portable library for worker thread pools and job queues and such

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am developing a portable (as in Linux and Windows) C/C++ program - a game - that will use multi-threading for the jobs such as path-finding.

Are there any robust libraries for handling the allocation of tasks to the thread-pool?  Preferably with lock-free structures and work-stealing and other cutting-edge ideas.  Or do I have to really start with pthreads or a threading library and then implement the job queuing and such myself?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [tbb](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/documentation.php) from Intel.  I haven't used their task groups, but it might give you a good starting point if you can't find anything better.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do your own threading, then use [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread.html).

As for thread-pools and task queuing, I think that [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is a good library to look at. It might not be using the cutting edge stuff and provide the most features, but it is portable, robust, and lock-free (I think). It is meant for asynchronous IO, but you can basically consider tasks as asynchronous message handlers.

TBB is also a good option, but it might be a bit of overkill for a computer game (it's more geared towards true parallel computing).